# Javascript - .map running out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js

My libraries:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('graceful-fs'));
const path = require('path');
const xml2js = Promise.promisifyAll(require('xml2js'));
```

I have a large number of XML files I want to parse. I am able to create an array of paths to all the files using this function:

```
function getFileNames(rootPath) {
  // Read content of path
  return fs.readdirAsync(rootPath)
    // Return all directories
    .then(function(content) {
      return content.filter(function(file) {
        return fs.statSync(path.join(rootPath, file)).isDirectory();
      });
    })
    // For every directory
    .map(function(directory) {
      // Save current path
      let currentPath = path.join(rootPath, directory);
      // Read files in the directory
      return fs.readdirAsync(currentPath)
        // Filter out the XMLs
        .filter(function(file) {
          return path.extname(file) === '.XML';
        })
        // Return path to file
        .map(function(file) {
          return path.join(rootPath, directory, file);
        });
    })
    // Flatten array of results
    .reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b);
    });
}
```

and now I want to go trough every single file and parse it.

I have 2 function to do so:

```
function openFile(filePath) {
 return fs.readFileAsync('./' + filePath)
  .then(function(fileData) {
    return fileData;
  });
}

function parseFile(data) {
  return xml2js.parseStringAsync(data)
      .then(function(xmlObject) {
        return xmlObject;
      });
}
```

Now when I call this with the .map (the `GetFileNames` function outputs an array with over 20k strings with file paths) function:

```
getFileNames('./XML')
  .map(function(file) {
    openFile(file)
      .then(function(data) {
        parseFile(data)
            .then(function(object) {
              console.log(object);
            });
      });
  });
```

I get a javascript heap out of memory error:

> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory

But when I run the function a single time by passing in the path to the actual file:

```
openFile('./XML/2016-10-1/EUROTIPOLD2016-10-1T00-00-22.5756240530.XML')
  .then(function(data) {
    parseFile(data)
        .then(function(object) {
          console.log(object);
        });
  });
```

I get the desired output.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you are saying when you somehow use a varaible instead of a hard coded string it works???

Comment: Sorry, edited the question. I am saying that when I run the function a single time without the .map function it works (by passing in a string with a path to the file). When I run it inside the .map function I run out of memory.

Comment: How many files did you try to open? Don't forget about async functions,  Node.js try to open all file at the same time, not one after one.

Comment: About 40k files, using graceful-fs for opening files, etc. Edited the question to show how this is done. Basically I would like to open every file separately, parse it, then move on.

Comment: Did you tried to use for cycle rather than map?

Comment: You need to understand about asynchronism in javascript. Your function .map will start 40k function which try to load data in memory. This is too much (if each file size is 1Mb, you try to allocate 40Gb of memory). And after you transform this data in js object (so basically 2*40 = 80Gb). You have to change the way for open all file (make a heap which manage your job, ...)

Comment: xszaboj, I don't think it would make any difference as the *parseFile()* returns a promise, so even the *for* loop will have many opened files together.

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič did you try to add the *catch()* part on each promise to see where it break up? Are those files with similar size or you have some huge file?

Comment: @MarioSantini The files are of different sizes(from 20kb - 5MB). I though that each iteration would wait for the promise to be fulfilled, and then move on with the next function call, not start 40k functions at once...

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič so you have to try with the big files to see if you have troubles. About promise, it is a way to write code in a concurrent manner, so it depends on who hanlde the promise in the first time, if the code is *blocking* or not.

Comment: people! (:   nobody was "diving" to problem. the script get out of heap because of uncontrolled async looping. 40K files are opened and parsed at same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating `nK` files happens asynchronous.

1) You're getting list of files

2) by doing `.map` You're calling `openFile`, `parseFile` that are async functions and it takes time to read and parse.

So because of asynchronousity it proceeds to next file without waiting to finish previous one to call garbage collector to sweep memory and here is insufficient memory problem.

Think about reading 20K files with different sizes at once.

So here is solution:

Use `async` to synchronize (`eachSeries`) or control (`eachLimit`) iteration.

```
const async = require('async'); // install: npm i --save async

let files = getFileNames('./XML');

// eachLimit(files, 3,
async.eachSeries(files, 
  (file, next) => { 
    openFile(file) 
     .then(
       parseFile, 
       (err) => {
         console.error('Cannot open file:', file, err);
         next();
       }) 
     .then(
       object => { // successfully parsed file, so log it out and proceed to next file
         console.log(object);
         next();
       }, 
       (err) => {
         console.error('Cannot parse data from file:', file, err);
         next();
       });
});
```

p.s. feel free to comment and fix code issue in my answer.

Comment: Did not use your code directly, but started using async.eachSeries, which solved my issues. Thanks

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič actually that was ~an example (: You're free to define Your code as You wish

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple case of more resource requirement for your workload. I would look at increasing heap size to meet your demand, rather than changing the source code.

I recommend `--max_old_space_size` to be setup accordingly to meet the requirement - it may be an iterative process though.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this could be a solution only if there is no other issues or in case of something like last resort. Is better to debug for issues first, and fix or optimize as possible and only if is strictly necessary you can proceed to provide more resources to the node process according with the load level of the server.